# How to return variables from a component using function as a child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I hope someone can shed light on this. Using the react `Route` component gave me this idea and I can't figure it out

The React `<Route>` component seems to render the children, but it also returns variables such as `match`. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
<Route exact path="/">
  {({ match }) => (
    <div>
      {`${JSON.stringify(match)}`}
    </div>
  )}
</Route>
```

Notice that even though `match` was not declared anywhere in the component, the variable is returned by `Route` so that it can be accessed in the children.

If I wanted to do this in one of my own components, how would this be accomplished?

I tried this:

```
const Test = (props: any): any => {
  return {
    testVariable: "test variable",
    render: (
      <>
        {props.children}
      </>
    ) 
  };
};
```

And would expect to be able to use it like this:

```
<Test>
  {({ testVariable }) => (
    <p>{testVariable}</p>
  )}
</Test>
```

But it now works as my expectation.

**EDIT:** This has been solved, thanks to *novonimo*'s answer below. I learned that the technical term for this functionality is called **Function as a Child Component (FaCC)**.

Here's a useful [tutorial](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/Using-Functions-as-Children-and-Render-Props-in-React-Components) that I was able to find after reading novonimo's answer.

Comment: Actually I'm not really sure what is your exact need, but if you want to return something from component you can pass a ```setState``` to child components.

Comment: I'm just wondering how it's possible to return multiple values from a component. You can see this in the example of the `<Route>` component in my post. When calling a react `<Route>`, the component also returns the `match` variable that can be used in the children. How is this done?

Comment: You can pass multiple props to child component like ```<component props1={setValues} props2={setValue2} />```. And you don't really need to return the variable explicitly because the state will change once you set its state in the child components.

Comment: @Bryce Yes, I know how to pass props and states to child components - I actually know my way around React quite well :P . I've just never seen the particular functionality I'm asking about documented anywhere, yet it's done with the `<Route>` component. Please see my desired use in the original post, I want to be able to return a variable/callback that can be accessed in the children without using a state or prop, the same as the React creators did it in the `<Route>` component with the `match` variable that's returned with the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very interesting and sometimes wired to facing.

I'll take a counter example to show you how you could do that:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";


const ChildComponent = ({children}) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(prevState => prevState + 1)
    }, 1000)
  }, [])

  return children(new Date(), counter)
}

const ParentComponent = () => (
    <ChildComponent>
      {(startedAt, currentNumber) => (<p>started at: {startedAt} and current number is : {currentNumber}</p>)}
    </ChildComponent>
);

export default ParentComponent
```

try it on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-cloud-uiwyr?file=/src/App.js)

##### Explanation:

There are two components, child and parent.

In the `ChildComponent`, a simple `counter` where implemented. it changes every 1000 milliseconds.

`children` is a standard property name for passing children to a component.

In the `ParentComponenet`, a function (() => {}) passed as a children to the `ChildComponent`, it's the key of solution,

So far, we passed a function as `children` into the `ChildComponent`. with every change on `countner` variable, the `ChildComponent` will re-render, and every time the `children(new Date(), counter)` will be called.

the `children` function is now called in every 1 second and causes re-rendering on `ChildComponent`. so in the `ParentComponent` the arrow function (which passed as children with two arguments) will invoke every 1 second.

Comment: @novonimo You're awesome. Thank you so much! Do you know why this isn't in the React documentation? I understand that the use-case for this particular functionality might be rare, but I'm surprised that it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: @novonimo Done and done. Thanks again for your helpful answer. I hope many future readers get some clarification from this as well! I assume that it would be a similar concept if this was done with a class component instead of a functional component?

Comment: it's can be also implemented in class components, you can try it own, but feel free to ask a question about it since my implementation is on Functional component @JordanArldt

Comment: just use the state in the constructor, and use the componentDidMount instead of "useEffect hook", also render and return as same as functional version @JordanArldt

Comment: Yep, I was able to figure it out with class components. It's very similar to your example except you do `return this.props.children(new Date(), counter);` in the `render` method and move the `setInterval` function into the `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: brilliant, that's the whole change. you are amazing @JordanArldt

Comment: I appreciate your help and the perfect example! You are amazing also :-) take care.